# cmap.set_under() and cmap.set_over() not appearing in colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, osmnx

I am trying to plot a color bar and I tried using `cmap.set_under()` and `cmap.set_over()`, however they do not appear on the plot, can anyone help me please?

**Here is the code:**

```
city = 'Portugal, Lisbon'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive', simplify=True)

G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)

nc =[whatever you would like]
ns=[whatever you would like]

cmap = copy(plt.cm.get_cmap('inferno_r'))
cmap.set_over((0.001462, 0.000466, 0.013866, 1.0))
cmap.set_under((0.988362, 0.998364, 0.644924, 1.0))
norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0.8, vmax=1.5)
sm = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])

fg_color = 'black'
fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_graph(G_nx, node_color=nc, node_size=ns, edge_linewidth=0.8, figsize = (80,40), show=False, bgcolor = 'white')
cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax, orientation='vertical', aspect=50, shrink=0.8)
cb.set_label('r', fontsize = 60, color = fg_color, rotation = 'horizontal')
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=40, color = fg_color)
# set colorbar tick color
cb.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(color=fg_color)


cb.outline.set_edgecolor(fg_color)
cb.cmap.set_over('k')


plt.setp(plt.getp(cb.ax.axes, 'yticklabels'), color=fg_color)

fig.set_frameon(True)
fig.savefig('dhgdhg.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try `fig.colorbar(..., extend='both')`? See [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html)

Comment: Ah it worked. What does extend do? Also you can answer the question with this comment and I''l mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fig.colorbar(..., extend='both')` adds little triangular arrows at the top and the bottom of the colorbar, to indicate the *over* and the *under* color. Instead of 'both', other options are 'min' and 'max', the default is 'neither'. For more info, see the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html).

Note that the default under color is equal to the lowest color of the colormap (similar for the default over color). In case these are the desired values, they don't need to be set explicitly.

Comment: If I don't write an argument then the colors on the triangles are the same. AT least that is what I get